# What does gvisor Endpoint represent in a forwarder

Tags: go, sockets, networking, gvisor

I find myself confused with the concept of Endpoints in gvisors netstack when i setup a stack linked to a TUN interface, the intercepted request must go through a handshake using gvisor r.CreateEndpoint(&wq). my mind goes like "since the handshake is done that's a connection (local/remote)" why writing to it doesn't write to remote (verified by Wireshark) but instead it writes back to local socket and read that should read what remote is saying but it doesn't, it reads from local socket.
i know this is dumb question but i'm sure i'm missing a big chunck of how the netstack route traffic

Hope someone can give a general concept of forwarder EndPoint.

Google nothing useful